# How do I display the selected value of the drop down list on gsp

Tags: javascript, grails, gsp

How do I display the selected value of the drop down list on gsp?

```
<g:select id="plantselect"
name="plant" from="${plantList.list()}" 
value="${plant.id}" />
```

Can't I to do something like ${plant} to display the selected value on view?

Comment: Do you want to display the select value of the drop down list on the same gsp ? or Do you want to display the selected value of the drop down on any field ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the following code in order to display the drop down value:

```
<html>
 <head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
  <title>Sample title</title>
  <script>
  function getValue(value)
  {
    alert(value);
    document.getElementById("test").style.display = "inline";
    document.getElementById("test").innerHTML  = value;

   // $("#test").html(value);

  }
 </script>
 </head>
 <body>
  <h1>Sample line</h1>
  <g:select id="plantselect"
        name="plant" from="${plantList.list()}" 
        optionKey="id" optionValue="id" onchange="getValue(this.value)"/>
 <!-- if you want to other field than id then change id to that field.-->
  <br/>

  <div id="test" style="display: none">
  </div>
 </body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

you should pass that selected id simply to your `gsp` form controller if it another domain value then access it using the

`domain.thislistdomain.id` in your jsp `Student.course.id` or some value selected and pass that id to the value of the g:select

:)

or on gsp itself you can do the following :

```
<g:javascript>
    $( "gselectidhere" ).change(function() {
      alert( "You selected"+this.val());
      //if you want to process and communicate at selection with the controller please add ajax post or get call here ...
    });

</g:javascript>
```

//or you can youse g:remote tag and please refer here :

[Grails remotefunction to populate dropdownlist with Jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14011400/grails-remotefunction-to-populate-dropdownlist-with-jquery)

Comment: I want to do a check before passing the selected value to the controller

Comment: Hi, I'm trying to check the selcted value and do an if else! So its basically on the same page. Say that i wanted to change the label name if the selected value is x...

Comment: @hey that is easy use the jquery function on change and do the normal java script IF then and then change the label ...i have already answered your question~!

Answer (score 0):

Sure, try this:

```
<g:select id="plaintselect" name="plant.id" from="${Plant.list()}" optionKey="id" required="" value="${plant?.id}" class="many-to-one"/>
```

Don't forget to override **toString()** in **Plant** class, cos this value is used by defolt to build optionValue for select.

See http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Tags/select.html for more info